# pandas.errors.ParserError arises when i'm reading a csv file, saying there's more fields than expected

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm reading csv file using pandas,

```
t = pd.read_csv("../imdb/title.csv",sep=',')
```

but a parse error arises when reading the following two lines,

```
line 9141: 124832,"Zehut Sh'ula\"",,7,1997,,Z324,124831,1,3,,3ecbb0386bee44d925ff0fcdb11e11b8
line 57059: 80501,"Co-Host Andy Cohen; \"Steel Magnolias\" Cast: Queen Latifah, Alfre Woodard, Jill Scott",,7,2012,,C2353,80464,2,26,,4ec914112555c0fb2180cc7cab41c671
```

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 9141, saw 14
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 57059, saw 14
```

I tried to change line 9141 into

```
124832,"Zehut Sh'ula",,7,1997,,Z324,124831,1,3,,3ecbb0386bee44d925ff0fcdb11e11b8
```

and the error disappeared. Does the characters '"' cause the problem?

Comment: You might try passing `escapechar='\\'` to `read_csv`.  Quote escaping within CSV files is not well standardized.